# Eclipse - JBoss 4.2.0GA runtime with JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6] interoperability

Tags: eclipse, jboss, java

Is JBoss 4.2.0GA operational with JavaSE-1.6? I have openjdk installed in Ubuntu. Whenever I am trying to set the Properties of a Dynamic Web Project to

1. JBoss 4.2 Runtime
2. JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]

The project explorer of Eclipse showing an error beside the project name.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is JBoss 4.2.0GA operational with JavaSE-1.6?<<

Absolutely, this is what we use in production.

Comment: @bestsss thank you for reply. What should I do to gain this compatibility?

Comment: @bestsss I found a patch in http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWithJDK6 can you please tell me how to use this patch.

Comment: @Tapas, what kind of an error to you see, I just use the jars as libraries and that's all. I do not use the patch (and actually didn't know of)... many of the libraries in server/xxx/lib can be replaced by some newer versions and that includes hibernate, jdbc drivers, etc.

Comment: ...also there are bugs in arjuna transaction manager (which we fixed in-house). We use heavily modified tomcat connector since tomcat 5.5 doesn't have working NIO. However, overall jboss 4.2 works with java6 just out of the box.

Comment: @bestsss the error is a red star in the left of the project name in eclipse's project explorer. It seems some build path problem. If I set JBoss 4.2 runtime with JavaSE-1.5 the error does not appears.

Comment: @Tapas, I do not know then, like I told I just use the jars as normal libraries while compiling and that's all. The red star doesn't tell much, but build path problem looks right on the target.